# Renderer function not work in magento grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid, renderer

I don't know what is the problem with my code.

**Gird**

```
    $this->addColumn('category', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('udropship')->__('Cateogry'),
                'index'     => 'category',
                'sortable'  => false,
                'filter'    => false,
                'renderer'  => 'Unirgy_DropshipPo_Block_Adminhtml_ReportItem_Bundle',
));
```

**Renderer Function**

```
class Unirgy_DropshipPo_Block_Adminhtml_ReportItem_Bundle extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return "work";
    }
}
```

Comment: any error in error log?

Comment: no. no any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove index from addcolumn because there is no field called as category in your collection

```
 $this->addColumn('category', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('udropship')->__('Cateogry'),

                'sortable'  => false,
                'filter'    => false,
                'renderer'  => 'Unirgy_DropshipPo_Block_Adminhtml_ReportItem_Bundle',
));
```

Comment: your most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error like this Mage_Udropship_Helper_Data not found.

### Error in this line

```
'header' => Mage::helper('udropship')->__('Cateogry'),
```

**`Mage::helper('DropshipPo')`** will be use instead **udropship.**
 ***udropship***
is not a module name.

Comment: not any error its display only empty cell

Comment: Try this Mage::helper('DropshipPo')->__('Cateogry')

Comment: Mage::helper('DropshipPo')->__('Cateogry') after this i got the error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_DropshipPo_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dropshippo/adminhtml_reportItem_bundle');
 
 echo get_class($block);

What is output of this ? can you paste here.

Comment: Try this 
Mage::helper('dropshippo')->__('Cateogry')

Comment: Lowercase letters in helper() method

Comment: don't worry try this  
Mage::helper('dropshippo')->__('Cateogry')

Comment: vote me & other will find best answer